# Django: Adding custom CSS in UpdateView

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to find a method of adding custom css to the form that is generated. What would be an appropriate way of adding custom css to those fields?

views.py

```
class ProfileUpdateView(UpdateView):
    template_name = "users/profileUpdate.html"
    model = models.User
    fields = (
        "first_name",
        "last_name",
        "about",
        "displayImg",
    )

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.request.user
```

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    about = models.TextField(default="")
    displayImg = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to="users")
```

profileUpdate.html

```
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button
            class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline w-full">Update</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: What do you mean with custom css, a css file, or add a class to a widget?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Adding a class to a widget. Sorry for not being clear

Comment: Please show the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a `ModelForm`, with the css attribute, for example:

```
# app/forms.py

from django import forms

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = (
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'about',
            'displayImg',
        )
        widgets = {
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'myclass'})
        }
```

Next we can "inject" that form in the class-based view:

```
# app/views.py

from app.forms import ProfileForm

class ProfileUpdateView(UpdateView):
    template_name = "users/profileUpdate.html"
    model = models.User
    form_class = ProfileForm

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.request.user
```

Answer (score 2):

Do the following:

```
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'special'}))
    url = forms.URLField()
    comment = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': '40'}))
```

Or for ModelForms use this:

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'special'})
        self.fields['comment'].widget.attrs.update(size='40')
```

Please see the source from the django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/widgets/#styling-widget-instances